# RoR4 Chess game Model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm working on a simple chess game application and am having some issues understanding how to use multiple associations and has_many, through association between my User (player), Game and Piece models. The models I am planning to create are:

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :white_games, class: :Game, foreign_key: :'white_user_id'            
  has_many :black_games, class: :Game, foreign_key: :'black_user_id'
  has_many :pieces, through: :games, source: :games         
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :white_user, class: :User, foreign_key: :'white_user_id'
  belongs_to :black_user, class: :User, foreign_key: :'black_user_id'
  has_many :pieces, foreign_key: :game_id
end

class Piece < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
end
```

This should use the custom foreign keys, and link each association as a single belongs_to call from Game model to each user (player) for the game.

I then extended this to the User model. In the game, each individual user will have multiple instances of the Game class, because a user can be part of multiple games at a time.

So the white_games represents all the games the player is part of where he/she is the white player -->maps to the belongs_to white_user in the game. And the black_games do the same for all the games the same user is involved in as the black_user.

Questions:

1) Are these associations set up correctly?

2) For the piece model, basically I want to just return all the pieces a user has for a particular game at a time.

Is this possible with using 'foreign key' with has_many pieces, then in user model specifying 'source' with has_many :pieces, through: :games?

So that when I call @user.pieces(game: game.id) it will do just that?

Answer (score 0):

```
has_many :pieces, foreign_key: :game_id
```

The foreign key here is not necessary because by default Rails will look for a foreign key named for the class. the class is `Game`, so by default Rails will look for `game_id` on the other model. It's Best Practice not to include things that Rails does by default. (the foreign keys on your black/white games are necessary because they are named something differently than just `<class>_id`)

```
has_many :pieces, through: :games, source: :games
```

this probably won't work because you don't have an association set up called `games` - you instead have `white_games` and `black_games`, so the `through` bit will go looking for this association and tell you that it can't be found.

For what you say you need of pieces - I don't think you need the association at all. You want pieces for a particular game of a user? then you will just fetch the game and then grab the pieces out of that game

```
game = current_user.white_games.find(params[:id])
# will return all pieces for this game, both white and black
pieces = game.pieces
```

If you want just the black-user's pieces... then you will need to add something to distinguish between white and black eg a column called `colour` to the `Piece` class.

Then you would be able to do something like this:

```
class Piece
  belongs_to :game
  scope :black -> { where(colour: "black") }
  scope :white -> { where(colour: "white") }
end


game = current_user.white_games.find(params[:id])
# will return all pieces for this game, both white and black
pieces = game.pieces
# just the black pieces
black_pieces = game.pieces.black
```

Comment: Thanks @taryn, that makes sense to me. Only problem is I would like to return only the white pieces for a game if the user is the white_user for the game and vice versa for the black_games. Any ideas how I would set up that using associations?

Comment: You can't unless you set the colour on the piece. if you ask for a king - how does the piece know if it's the white king or the black king? If you set the colour on the piece, then you can also set up conditions on the associations that only fetch out that colour. But I'm not sure you can do it easily with just associations. Certainly not as simply as you have above. It would take some complex SQL... which is doable. Are you good with SQL?

Comment: Yes I will have a color field for the Piece model. Thanks that helped alot!

Comment: Right so you'll need something like the following logic (note this is pseudo code, not actual code): "where piece.game_id = game.id && (if user.id == game.white_user_id THEN piece.colour = white ELSE piece.colour = black)"

Comment: I think I just got confused by the use of has_many, through for nested associations. I thought that may be since a piece belongs to a game, and a game belongs to a User with a foreign key that specified white or black user that may be rails will enable me to return just the pieces with the game_id and the foreign key somehow. As for the SQL i've only done basics SQL programming, so wouldn't  really know where to start to solve this...

Comment: yeah, but you don't really have just a game, you have blackgames and whitegames... you have exactly the tools that you have written yourself... ;) The pieces belong to the game - so if you fetch them you will get all of them. if you want the pieces belonging to a user, then you'd need to also add `user_id` to the pieces too. then you could get `game.white_user.pieces`